# Increase and Decrease Quantity of products in angular 12

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, angular8, angular12

I am trying to add no. of quantity for a product using angular 12 but when i clicked on add button but its adding for all products like shown in image.
[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR8yU.png)

> **HTML Code**

```
 <div class="card-content">
    <h3 class="title">{{food.FoodName}}</h3>
    <h2 class="subtitle">{{food.Rate | currency:"INR"}}</h2>

    <div class="actions">
      <ion-buttons>
        <ion-button (click)="addtoCart(food)">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <div class="counter" style="font-size: 2rem">{{quantity}}</div>
        <ion-button (click)="removeCart(food)">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="remove"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**TS Code**

```
quantity: number = 0;

addtoCart(food: any) {        
    this.quantity++;
    console.log(food);
 }
```

Comment: I'm assuming the html is in an `ngFor`, is that corrrect? If so all your food items reference the same `quantity` property so when it changes they all change.  Put the quantity on the food object itself so you can maintain a quantity for each food item.

Comment: @Jason White yes HTML is in `ngFor`. You mean to have one more property called quantity inside Food object itself ??

Comment: Yes, if you want to maintain a quantity count for each item.  Or you could create a separate component and pass the food object down to the child component and the child component will have the quantity property.

Comment: Yes thanks got the solution

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single variable to store the quantity. This won't store it for all items. You need to add the quantity in the `food` object itself so that each `food` item has its own quantity in the list.

**Note:** It's better to add `quantity` property to each `food` object when you fetch/add to the list of `food` items. The below code would work with the current situation though:

```
addtoCart(food: any) { 
     if(food.quantity){ // if quantity already exists on food object
       food.quantity++;
    }else{
    food.quantity=1;//if quantity does not exist on food object, add it
    }
    console.log(food);
 }
```

Changes in HTML: Assuming that you are looping through multiple `food` objects, display the quantity of that particular `food`.

```
<div class="counter" style="font-size: 2rem">{{food?.quantity || 0}}</div>
```

Comment: For the html you'll probably have to do a null check for the quantity `{{ food?.quantity || 0 }}` if you're adding the quantity property on `addtoCard`.